Why am I getting `permission denied` upon execution of `docker-entrypoint.sh` only with docker compose?
I'm trying to have a containerized app up and running. This is done through a docker compose file where all the needed servies are detailed. In particular one service is giving me the following error upon container creation: error: exec: "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh": stat /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: permission denied.
This service is a simple postgres database and is declared as follows in the docker-compose.yml:
db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:16-alpine
    volumes:
      - ./postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - ./.env


the .env file sets the following variables:
DB_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
POSTGRES_HOST=db
POSTGRES_DB=djangodb
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_USER=<some_user>
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<some_password>


This is my architecture:
neofetch output
and the output from docker info:
Client:
 Version:    27.3.1
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  0.18.0
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  2.30.3
    Path:     /usr/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
 Containers: 6
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 6
 Images: 7
 Server Version: 27.3.1
 Storage Driver: vfs
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 207ad711eabd375a01713109a8a197d197ff6542.m
 runc version: 
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: builtin
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 6.11.6-zen1-1-zen
 Operating System: Arch Linux
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 8
 Total Memory: 15.34GiB
 Name: arch-g33579
 ID: ***
 Docker Root Dir: /run/media/***/docker-data
 Debug Mode: false
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled

I tried the following:

remove the volume bind mount

remove the environment file to make it run with default values

foce the user to be root with user: root directive in the docker compose file

download the files from the offical postgres docker image repository and build my own image locally, adding
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chown postgres:postgres /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

bedore the actual call to the entrypoint.


Nothing changed.
When I run the same image through docker run -it -v ./postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:16-alpine /bin/bash the container is created with no problems and I'm dropped into a shell.
This makes me think that this is a problem related to docker compose itself but I don't know how to solve this. Any suggestion would be very appreciated, thank you.

"I'm dropped into a shell"... that doesn't seem possible because you're running an Alpine image but calling /bin/bash

Have you ever tried to build: a modified database image?  Does it help to docker pull postgres:16-alpine, making sure you have the official Docker Hub image?

Have you looked at the first #! line of docker-entrypoint.sh to see what handler it's trying to run?

@Phil I'm sorry but I don't quite get your point... With that I wanted to try if I was able to attach to the running container. I know bash is not the default shell in alpine but is there a problem in calling another shell as bash?

@timroberts the first line is #!/usr/bin/env bash where usr/bin/env just sets a bunch of environment variables. bash is a valid shell from /etc/shells

@davidmaze thank you for the suggestions. As I was stating in point 4 yes, I tried to build a modified image, tagging it as postgres:own to not overwrite the official one. I tried to pull the postgres:16-alpine image before executing docker compose up but nothing changed

For what it's worth, /usr/bin/env doesn't "set a bunch of environment variables".  Instead, it searches the PATH to find the executable named in its first parameter.  It's used when the location of the executable is not consistent from machine to machine.  Since bash is always /bin/bash, you don't typically use it for bash.

@timroberts I'm sorry for my presumption in the last comment, and thank you for correcting me. Btw the application I'm trying to run is open source and available on GitHub. Should I put the link to that in the post?
